# How to delete consecutive occurrences of an event in a R dataframe?

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have a R dataframe containing date info about generic events:
id;start_date;end_date.

Sometimes the **same event** may occur the same day (1) or at a distance of one day (2), for example:

(1)
1001;2016-05-07;2016-05-11
1001;2016-05-11;2016-05-14

(2)
1001;2016-05-07;2016-05-11
1001;2016-05-12;2016-05-14

In the first case the event "1001" ends and restarts the same day, while in the second case that event ends on 2017-05-11 and starts again the day after. I'd like to delete the second occurrence of the event in both cases.
If the second occurrence is at a distance of two or more days, it's ok to preserve the second occurrence. How can I do this in R?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would be your approach to this? And could you paste sample data, e.g. using `dput()` function.

Comment: I used to solve this kind of problem in SQL. In R I think it can be useful to _group_by_ (dplyr) the rows on the column **id** and then _filter_ in any way the groups, but I've ho idea about the condition of the filter.

Comment: Look at `mondate` package to calculate difference between dates. 2nd of all, why not use the `unique` function if your 2 day condition is met?

Comment: `lubridate` also works fine with dates. The only problem would be to reshape the data. Maybe you can "misalign" the `start_date` and `end_date` columns by one and simply subtract them?

Comment: @M.D no problem with the reshape, I'm very comfortable with it. So imagine I have data in this format (id;variable;value):

1001;start_date;2016-05-07
1001;end_date;2016-05-11
1001;start_date;2016-05-11
1001;end_date;2016-05-14

How can I say to R to delete the 3rd and the 4th row?

Comment: I will post it as an answer for the readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution with my guess of how data look like:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id = c(1001,1001,1001,1001),
                  start_date = as.Date(c("2016-05-07", "2016-05-11", "2016-05-07", "2016-05-12")),
                  end_date = as.Date(c("2016-05-11", "2016-05-14", "2016-05-11", "2016-05-14")))

dat2 <- data.table(id = c(dat$id, NA),
                   start_date = c(dat$start_date, NA),
                   end_date = c(as.Date(NA), dat$end_date))

dat2[, dif := end_date - start_date]
```

Then you can just remove rows with `dif <= 0` I guess.

I've used the `data.table` package, but you can just do `dat2$dif <- dat2$end_date - dat2$start_date`.